# how to find one hop sender node in ns2 dsragent?

Tags: ns2

I want to find out which node in neighborhood sent me a packet that I am receiving in `recv` function in `dsragent`. I use the following packet header but they don't have previous address.

```
hdr_sr *srh = hdr_sr::access(packet);
hdr_ip *iph = hdr_ip::access(packet);
hdr_cmn *cmh =  hdr_cmn::access(packet);
```

Answer (score 0):

The sending node shall modify one of the header, otherwise telling will obviously be impossible. Since we don't know what your application looks like, I can't tell you which header is appropriate to modify.